# Realm only write around 20 objects in device

Tags: react-native, realm

Realm only write 20 objects
anybody have faced this kind of issue?
any testcases or debug method also helpfull for me to resolved my issue.

Comment: the error is in your transaction code, considering I've saved 3000+ objects in one transaction before and it worked just fine. You probably execute `realm.executeTransactionAsync()` in a loop or something.

Comment: I'm Using Reactnative to developed application, does it support realm.executeTransactionAsync() method?